# What integer values are assigned to a series of enumerations without identifiers?

Tags: c, enums

A piece of code I've been working with has a series of enumerations without identifiers. As I understand it, each enumerator is assigned an integer value based on its position in the enumeration list. The first enumerator is given the value of 0, the next, 1 and so forth.

In the example below, what integers would be assigned to each enumerator? Would APPLE = 0, ORANGE = 1, BANANA = 2, GRAPE = 3, etc.

```
enum {APPLE, ORANGE, BANANA};
enum {GRAPE, PEAR};
enum {PEACH, GRAPEFRUIT};
```

Comment: Have you tried printing them?

Answer (score 1):

Each enumeration is separate and will assign the value of `0` to the first item. Each subsequent item in the same enumeration will, of course, be assigned a value one higher than the previous.

So, `APPLE`, `GRAPE` and `PEACH` have a value of 0, `ORANGE`, `PEAR`, and `GRAPEFRUIT` have a value of 1, and `BANANA` has a value of 2

Answer (score 1):

ÀPPLE, ORANGE and BANANA will have values 0,1 and 2. This is then restarted for GRAPE and PEAR. The it's restarted again. So APPLE=GRAPE=PEACH=0, ORANGE=PEAR=GRAPEFRUIT=1 and BANANA=2.

From the C11 standard:

> The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted.) An enumerator with = defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression. **If the first enumerator has no =, the value of its enumeration constant is 0. Each subsequent enumerator with no = defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by adding 1 to the value of the previous enumeration constant.** (The use of enumerators with = may produce enumeration constants with values that duplicate other values in the same enumeration.) The enumerators of an enumeration are also known as its members.

https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2p3